# Casting CharBuffer and StringBuilder to superinterface

Tags: java, stringbuilder, charsequence

Both StringBuilder and CharBuffer implement CharSequence  and Appendable interfaces. 
When declaring the superinterface

```
 public  interface IAppendableCharSequence extends CharSequence, Appendable{}
```

then I can cast CharBuffer to IAppendableCharSequence, but not StringBuilder:

```
 private IAppendableCharSequence m_buffer;

 // ...

 m_buffer = (IAppendableCharSequence) CharBuffer.allocate(512); // ok


 m_buffer = (IAppendableCharSequence) new StringBuilder(512); // Cannot cast from StringBuilder to IAppendableCharSequence
```

Why is that? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I can cast CharBuffer to IAppendableCharSequence

Actually you can't. You can only cast an instance of a class to a type that the class deliberately implements. The fact that a CharBuffer implements Appendable and CharSequence does not mean it implements the IAppendableCharSequence interface.

The compiler allows the cast because it cannot tell what exactly will be returned by `CharBuffer.allocate(512)`. As far as the compiler knows, it could return a subclass of CharBuffer that does explicitly implement IAppendableCharSequence. But if the object doesn't really implement that interface, the cast will throw a ClassCastException at run time.

Whereas, `new StringBuilder(512)` guarantees that the new object is a StringBuilder and not a subclass of that, so the compiler can see at compile time that the cast won't work.

One solution to your problem is to make a generic wrapper that does implement your interface:

```
public static <T extends CharSequence & Appendable> IAppendableCharSequence wrap(T t) {
    if (t == null) throw new NullPointerException();
    final CharSequence csq = t;
    final Appendable a = t;
    return new IAppendableCharSequence() {
        @Override
        public int length() {
            return csq.length();
        }

        @Override
        public char charAt(int index) {
            return csq.charAt(index);
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence subSequence(int start, int end) {
            return csq.subSequence(start, end);
        }

        @Override
        public Appendable append(CharSequence s) throws IOException {
            a.append(s);
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Appendable append(CharSequence s, int start, int end) throws IOException {
            a.append(s, start, end);
            return this;
        }

        @Override
        public Appendable append(char c) throws IOException {
            a.append(c);
            return this;
        }
    };
}
```

(The declared `csq` and `a` variables are not strictly necessary there, since one can call the same methods on `t` directly, but the extra variables make the returned IAppendableCharSequence object a little faster by avoiding it needing to do a cast every time one of its methods is called. Declaring those variables also does an early safety check that the caller hasn't bypassed the generics, which would otherwise cause failure only when trying to use the returned IAppendableCharSequence.)

Once you have that method, you can do both of these:

```
m_buffer = wrap(CharBuffer.allocate(512));
m_buffer = wrap(new StringBuilder(512));
```

You can also call it with anything else that implements both CharSequence and Appendable.

Answer (score 4):

Neither of those will actually work at runtime, but the reason that the compiler permits one and not the other is that `StringBuilder` is `final` and `CharBuffer` isn't.

The compiler knows for sure that nothing that is an `instanceof StringBuilder` can ever be a valid implementation of `IAppendableCharSequence` because `StringBuilder` itself does not implement that interface, and being `final` it can have no subclasses.  So there are no circumstances in which that cast can ever be legal, and the compiler rejects it.

In the case of `CharBuffer` the compiler doesn't have that assurance, because you might create a custom subclass of `CharBuffer` that *does* implement `IAppendableCharSequence`.

The rules for which casts are allowable by the compiler and which aren't is in the Java Language Specification, in this case [section 5.1.6](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.6) (narrowing reference conversion), which among other things permits a conversion

> From any class type `C` to any non-parameterized interface type `K`, provided that `C` is not `final` and does not implement `K`

I.e. a cast from any class type to any interface type not implemented by the class is valid *provided the class is not final*.

Answer (score 1):

@Ian Roberts is correct.

The other part of the puzzle is that the Java type system treats  `IAppendableCharSequence` as more than just `CharSequence` and `Appendable`.  It is actually a type in its own right that *could* have associated semantics ... such that "any old class" that is both a `CharSequence` and `Appendable` does not qualify.

This means that nether `CharBuffer` or `StringBuilder` *is-a* `IAppendableCharSequence`, even though they both implement the `CharSequence` and `Appendable` interfaces.

Java interfaces are more that C or C++ aliases, even if they only extend other interfaces ...